# Xampp isn't working properly!

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have been facing a problem for 3 days.
When I install xampp on my windows-10, it's only working for the first time.
But when I shut down my pc, then I can't find it on installed app and also it wasn't visible on the system tray!! But, if I install it again, then it's working!
I don't know why it's happening.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Windows